# Move AutomaticMigrationsEnabled and AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to Web.config

Tags: linq-to-entities, code-first

I have these two properies set in my DbMigrationsConfiguration for Linq to entities:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
```

They are hardcoded in the constructor. This worked fine, but now when I want to deploy to production I want these values to be changed. Typically I would put these in the web.config, but I am not sure how best to do this.

Does anyone have any advise on how to get these out of code and into config?

Answer (score 0):

I added a static class to the class library. I assigned values from the static class library to the config file. I set the static values on startup of my program.